# Do we need Dagger annotation @Singleton in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependency-injection, dagger-2

It seems Lambda has some logic to only use one and same instance/object in one container. For all the requests come to this container, Lambda will create the instance first time then reuse it afterwards.
So, it seems `@Singleton` is not useful/necessary here since Lambda will handle to keep one instance and reuse.

But I saw a lot of Lambda code with Dagger using `@Singleton`. I was wondering if point above is wrong or if there is any other reason to use `@Singleton` in Lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, AWS Lambda scales by creating new execution environments. Each environment has a JVM that runs your code. Lambda is responsible for making sure that each environment only handles a single request at a time.

There could be many different reasons why code might be written with a @Singleton annotation. Maybe the code has come from another code base, is used in a different environment, or just because that's how the application is written.